# How to connect to MsAccess 2016 .accdb file that is in Sharepoint via Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2016

Am trying to create an Excel VBA User form. The data that is entered in that form should be stored in the MS Access 2016 .accdb file. It works when both the excel file (which has the user form and vba code) and the .accdb MsAccess file are in the same local machine.

Is there a possibility to keep both the excel file and the .accdb file in Sharepoint so that everyone will download the excel from sharepoint and update their data in the user form.

From the locally downloaded excel file, the excel vba code should be able to update the .accdb file that is still in the sharepoint.

If yes, can someone please share the connection-uri template or other means of achieving the same.

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864673/excel-vba-to-query-ms-access-database-on-sharepoint-with-adodb-not-a-valid-fi) of any help?

Comment: Exactly this is what I wanted to achieve. I will give a try. Thanks @Storax

Answer (score 1):

If the Access DB is really in SharePoint I don't think you are going to make much progress with this.  As you know, you really need to download Excel or the VBA part simply won't work.  Basically, VBA doesn't work in a web-based (cloud) environment.  Using VBA, you can import data from the cloud, but that's a completely different thing because the application is running from your desktop.  Anyway, just take the DB and move it to a folder on your network, and point Excel to that.  You don't need SharePoint for any of this.  Finally, the UNC path could literally be anything you want, just map it correctly.

Something like this should work just fine (starts with 2 backslashes).

\\my.corp.com\Your_DB_Name.accdb

Comment: This sounds working to me. Let me give a quick try and come back on this. Thanks @asher